# Is it accessible to wrap a whole 'card' in an <a> tag?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

In my website I have 'cards', each one with many elements (image, text, dates, etc.). It's kind of like a tweet card in twitter:

[image]

I want the whole card to be clickable (which should be a link to another page).

At the moment, I have the top level element as an `<a>` tag and use `aria-label` and `aria-describedby` so it's read correctly by a screen reader.

```
<a
   href="/some-url"
   aria-label="Honda VFR. Price: $10,000. Kilometers: 10,000. Listed yesterday."
   aria-describedby="description-1"
   >
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/1983_Honda_Interceptor_VF750F.jpg/300px-1983_Honda_Interceptor_VF750F.jpg" alt="Honda VFR picture" height="100" />

  <p>Honda VFR</p>

  <div>
    <p>$10,000</p>
    <p>Kms: 10,000</p>
    <p>Date listed: yesterday</p>
    <p id="description-1">This bike is pretty great and a lot of other details go here</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

I considered doing `aria-labelledby="title-id-1 price-id-1 distance-id-1"` but I found it read better by explicitly creating a summary sentence.

I am relying on the fact that the screen reader will ignore everything inside the `<a>` tag (if I have an `aria-label`). Is this a safe bet?

This all *seems* a bit strange, but I would like to know if there's any specific reason that I shouldn't do this.

Unfortunately the design dictates that the whole card is clickable, so just making only specific parts links is not an option.

The other option is to use a div, [aria roles like this](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/link/link.html) and JavaScript, which feels like a step in the wrong direction.

Any help is much appreciated.

jsbin: https://output.jsbin.com/kusawu

Comment: Do you have a Codepen / JSBin etc with an example that you can share? 

I've previously had great success when checking accessibility by switching on VoiceOver on my iPhone, and then loading up the relevant page in the browser to listen to how the page is rendered into audio. If the audio sounds sensible, then I expect it would be accessible to the majority of blind people.

Comment: Thank you, I had been lazy and not made the effort to setup a screen reader. I think this works well (on Android at least): https://output.jsbin.com/kusawu

Comment: This article adds some interesting details and tips regarding block level links and screen readers: https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/a11y-links.html#link-block-level-elements-with-care

Comment: related: [How accessible is it to nest multiple tags inside an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65681541/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it accessible to wrap a whole 'card' in an  tag?

"Accessibility" is a wild concept.

For instance, if you have low vision and use a screenreader to help you read the text inside your "card". Having the `aria-label` may prevent the screenreader from reading the content you can partly read. Which means : you know there's a content, you can quite read it, but your screenreader reads another thing different.

That being said, within your examples, it seems that it improves accessibility : user have access to the same content, but in plain english, which is appreciable.

So I don't see it as a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> this probably isn't a thing you need to rely on JavaScript for anymore. Since HTML5, this is perfectly valid:
>
> ```
> <a href="http://example.com">
>   <div>
>      anything
>   </div>
> </a>
> ```

Source: [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/)

Comment: Yes the question isn't "is it valid HTML". The question is - is it accessible. For example, will that word "anything" be read by a screen reader? I don't think it will, therefore this is actually quite a bad thing to do.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson what makes you suggest screen readers won't read the contents of the link? I just tested with VoiceOver and it read "link - anything" as expected. I would be very surprised to learn of other screen readers behaving differently.

Comment: I stand corrected, "anything" will be read. But if there is an `aria-label` on the `<a>` then VoiceOver doesn't read the contents. And I want an `aria-label` to succinctly describe what the link points to.