# Use the browser/system default behaviour on window.open(url)?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I am working on making some cards more accessible. To do so, I need to use JavaScript to take the one link from the Card Title and apply it to all elements inside the card.

It is working relatively well.

The problem, though, is that it is opening the link in a new TAB every time I click. Not just when I hold down CMD (Mac).

I know some users (like me) love this. But it is over riding the default behaviour and I'd like to some how find a way to get **window.open(url)** to just follow the default behaviours that the user is used to using.

I've tried:

```
window.open(url, "_blank")
window.open(url, "_self")
window.open(url, "_top")
```

JavaScript below:

```
        function cardLinks() {
            let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

            cards.forEach(function (box) {
                let link = box.querySelector("a");
                if (link) {
                    let url = link.getAttribute("href");
                    box.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        window.open(url)

                    });
                }
            });
        }
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            if ("querySelector" in document) {
                cardLinks();
            }
        });
```

If you have read this far, the reason this is important (to me at least) is that having seperate link tags on the HTML card element is a nightmare for accessibility users. As they need to tab through multiple links. Having an event handler on all the children of the card means that it works well for accessibility users and visual users.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: can you try window.open("https://www.url.com","_self"), please note Url should be prepended with protocol

Comment: Thanks @ManuJanardhanan, :)

Is the protocol not included with the `let url = link.getAttribute("href");`

Comment: then try location.href

Comment: I guess the easiest solution would be putting the entire card in the `<a>`.

Comment: Maybe try `link.click()`?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't (or don't want to) wrap the whole card in an anchor?

Comment: Hey @AlexanderNied, I can't do it that way as screen readers will see the link and then read the entire contents of the card to the user. Makes for a pretty poor experience for those who use screen readers. 

Any thoughts?

Comment: Fair point-- I wasn't really certain if that would make for a better or worse experience.  On one hand, if you're navigating through all anchors only you want enough context to know what the link is, but not so much that you get superfluous information.

Comment: @GlenHarry Have a look at [Is it accessible to wrap a whole 'card' in an <a> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42822083/1048572) and [How accessible is it to nest multiple tags inside an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65681541/1048572). Apparently you can use the `aria-label` to control what should be read out.